# How to render two sets of data in handlebars on matching name value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have webpage rendered in handlebars and express. The data is driven by a JSON document that has two objects, one is a set of dates and the other contains details.  Each date dynamically creates a web page with the required data. Below is a simple example of the data I am working with.

**JSON**

```
{
    "calendar": {
        "jan01": {
            "date": "January 1st",
            "weather": "cloudy"

        },
        "jan02": {
            "date": "January 2nd",
            "weather": "sunny"
        },
        ...
        "dec31": {
            "date": "December 31st",
            "weather": "cloudy"
        }
    },
    "weatherDetails": {
        "sunny": {
            "img": "https://sunny image"
        },
        "cloudy": {
            "img": "http://cloudy image"
        }
    }
}
```

I am passing the data from express via the following:

```
routes.get('/day/:date', (req, res) => {
  const urlDate = req.params.date
  res.render('day', {
    day: calendar[urlDate].date,
    weather: calendar[urlDate].weather
})
```

I can pull the actual word (sunny or cloudy) but I want to also get the corresponding image link in the weatherDetails object.

I am not sure where to start thinking of the solution. Whether it is to create a new object by merging the data on matching names or is there a helper function in handlebars that can do this.

Comment: Your code is incomplete (missing curly brackets and closing parens). Can you confirm that your code does not have these problems? Also, the code technically looks correct after those issues are fixed. Do you have a specific exception? We need more details.

Comment: I paraphrased the data and code to limit it to the relevant portions. the webpage itself renders fine. 

perhaps a better explanation is required. How can I render the image links in the weatherDetails object without needing to put the image link as part of each date in the calendar object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming calendar here is the object for the calendar key in your JSON object and so you have another variable called weatherDetails that has the object for the weatherDetails key in your JSON object.

Why not just resolve the image and pass it in as another key in the object you are passing in to the render function

```js
routes.get('/day/:date', (req, res) => {
  const urlDate = req.params.date
  res.render('day', {
    day: calendar[urlDate].date,
    weather: calendar[urlDate].weather,
    weatherImage: weatherDetails[calendar[urlDate].weather].img 
})
```

This is assuming that all the weather conditions are accounted for in the weatherDetails object in the JSON file.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't considered nesting the the object that way.